# Codemirror - setup custom display text and actions for hint

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I'm trying to implement code complete for Java. I'm trying to use the show-hint plugin.

```
javaEditor.on("keyup", function (cm, event) {
  CodeMirror.commands.autocomplete(cm, null, {
  completeSingle: false,
  hint : function(cm, options) {
    return CodeMirror.hint.fromList(cm, {words: arrayOfWords});
  }
}
```

This works of completing the words as entered. I want to have a few other use customization.

1. Different display text and shortcuts. For example, sysout and auto complete should be able to replace or with System.out.println()
2. Imports: For HashMap, I should be able to complete it and then include 'import Java.util.HashMap;' at the top of the file.
3. When comparing methods, the cursor should be placed within the parenthesis, instead of the end of the completion.

I see that these should be possible based on the documentation, but I don't see any documentation or examples on how to do.

Comment: I have the same problem ... I only need to thing like display to me in list label and when I selected then type on codemirror a value of label  ... so if you can solved it can you help me plz @JackDaniels

Comment: I am not knew what I have to do with codemirror to do it I try a lot  ... so can help  @JackDaniels